# Language C: convert a number grade into a letter grade

Tags: c, function

I'm new to programming (C) and I have a to do an exercise where I have to create a function that convert European style grade ( 1/20 to 20/20) to an American Style grade: for example an grade from 16 to 20 would be "A".
The I have to integrate it to the main program which will ask the grade to convert.

Here is what I have done so far, but it doesn't work (When I type a number from 1 to 20, I get "null" instead of a letter from A to F):

```
char chartype;
char convert( int i){
    switch(i){
        case 16 ... 20:
        chartype = "A";
        break;
        case 13 ... 15:
        chartype = "B";
        break;
        case 10 ... 12:
        chartype = "C";
        break;
        case 8 ... 9:
        chartype = "D";
        break;
        case 6 ... 7:
        chartype = "E";
        break;
        case 0 ... 5:
        chartype = "F";
        break;
        default:
        chartype = "X";
        break;      
}
}

char convert (int note);

int main(){

    int note;
    char lettre = convert(note);
    printf("Quelle est la note à convertir?\n");
    scanf("%d", &note);


    printf("%s\n", lettre);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: return the char e.g   case 13 ... 15: return "B"

Comment: *it doesn't work* isn't a useful diagnosis.  What do you mean *it doesn't work* ?  It calculates the wrong result ?  It fails to compile ?  Black holes form in the corner of your bedroom when you execute the code ?

Comment: `case 16 ... 20` is not (standard) C syntax and your `convert` function is missing a `return`, invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: ***How*** doesn't it work? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and check [this SO question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And read all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/.

Comment: You should probably take a few steps back, get a book or two, and start over from the very beginning. Don't learn programming by guessing, learn by actually learning.

Comment: `i` and `chartype` are terrible names.  Change them to something like `numberGrade` and `letterGrade`.

Comment: As already mentioned: `case 16 ... 20:` is no valid standard C syntax. Instead, you could write `case 16: case 17: case 18: case 19: case 20:`. Alternatively, you could write a "cascade" of `if`s but, actually, the `switch` is more effecient in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a string a look up the appropriate entry:

```
char convert(int numberGrade ){
   if (numberGrade >=0 && numberGrade  <= 20) {
           // 012345678901234567890      
      return "FFFFFFEEDDCCCBBBAAAAA"[numberGrade];
   }
   return 'X'
}
```

**EDIT**

Also you need to move the call to the convert function *After* you enter in the value.

See below:

```
int main(){
    int note;
    printf("Quelle est la note à convertir?\n");
    scanf("%d", &note);
    char lettre = convert(note);

    printf("%c\n", lettre);  // use %c with `char`, not %s
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C, strings are character arrays, and by `"___"` you mean a string literal means a character array.
`'_'`  is a character. format specifier for a character is %c, that is written in `printf` statement

Try this:

```
char convert( int i){
       if(i>20) return 'X';
       if(i>=16) return 'A';
       if(i>=13) return 'B';
       if(i>=10) return 'C';
       if(i>=8) return 'D';
       if(i>=6) return 'E';
       if(i>=0) return 'F';
       return 'X';
}

int main(){

    int note;
    char lettre;
    printf("Quelle est la note à convertir?\n");
    scanf("%d", &note);
    lettre = convert(note);

    printf("%c\n", lettre);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JulienMayard Are you use `"` or `'` in `if(i>20) return 'X';`?

Comment: Thank you @Anubhav for your help. It gives the expected result.

Comment: You might consider returning a value other than `X` for either the over-range out under-range to distinguish between the two conditions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are right but It was the question's requirement.

Answer (score 1):

That's not switch/case syntax in C. You should either create a case for each number:

```
switch(i){
        case 20:
        case 19:
        case 18:
        case 17:
        case 16:
        chartype = "A";
        break;
        ...
}
```

Or check like this `if (i <= 20 && i >= 16)`

There are other errors: "A" is not the same as 'A'; you try to convert an uninitialized value; there is no `return` statement in your `convert` function